# how to add a condition when searching in VIM?

Tags: search, vim, plugins, format

how to add a condition when searching in VIM?

**input:**

```
int myFoo(int)   ;
int myFoo      (     int) ;
int myFoo   (  int  );
int myFoo ( int );
```

**output:**

```
int myFoo ( int );
int myFoo ( int );
int myFoo ( int );
int myFoo ( int );
```

how do I do the search and replace correctly?

I can do the usual search and replace.

```
:g/ *(/s//\ (/g 
:g/( */s//\( /g
:g/ *)/s//\ )/g 
:g/) */s//\)/g
```

**But is there an easier way?**

Comment: Do you want to cater for nested parentheses? Do you want to cater for opening and closing parentheses on different lines?

Answer (score 0):

What does "easier" mean, here? Do you find your current solution difficult?

It is overcomplicated, that's for sure, as you don't need `:help :global` to begin with. So you can make it *simpler*:

```
:%s/ *(/\ (/g 
:%s/( */\( /g
:%/s/ *)/\ )/g 
:%s/) */\)/g
```

And you can simplify it further by removing the `g` flag because there is only one match on each line:

```
:%s/ *(/\ ( 
:%s/( */\( /
:%/s/ *)/\ )
:%s/) */\)
```

It is also possible to do it all with a single substitution:

```
:%s/ *( *\(\S*\) *) */( \1 )
```

[image: sub]

but I am not sure that qualifies as "easier".

The better way would be to let some external formatter (set via `:help 'formatprg'`) deal with the problem via a simple `gq<motion>`.